# CQL no viable alternative at input '12345' (CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [12345]...)">

Tags: python, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-python-driver

I am creating a cassandra table if the table does not exist with Python code below:

```
cluster = cassandra_cluster.Cluster([settings.CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINT], 
    settings.CASSANDRA_PORT)
session = cluster.connect(settings.CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE)
session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(id uuid PRIMARY 
   KEY,input text,predicted_result text,timestamp timestamp" % modelId)
```

When I set modelID = 12345, error appears in the terminal.

```
SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL 
query] message="line 1:27 no viable alternative at input '12345' ( 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [12345]...)">
```

What's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra table name cannot started with numeric character. Encapsulate them with double quotes if need to do so. Eg. `"12345"` or `"%s"`